# Eloquent mysql where statement in splited data column?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

My Users table:

table_users

```
id | name
1  | Jhon Doe
2  | Jhon Doe
3  | Jhon Doe
4  | Jhon Doe
```

My table example:

table_files

```
id | file_name | access_users (varchar 255 or any)
1  | exmp.xls  | 1,2,3
2  | other.xls | 1,3
3  | logo.png  | 2,3,4
```

My logged in user id: 2

select file_name from table_files where 'my logged in user id ' in access_users...

the results i want:

```
exmp.xls
logo.png
```

So I have a column containing the user ids and if the logged in user id is in this column, I want it to be listed and if not, I want an empty response.

How can I write a query for this?

Comment: If you could add a , in access_users in the begging and in the end of each element you could use LIKE '%,' + id ',%'

Comment: try `FIND_IN_SET`, better to change schema, dont store as comma separated value. store in separate table.

Comment: Change your database design.

Comment: this project is low user count. Max users 15-20